# How to find multiplier for a given number that will result in another given number?

Tags: arithmetic

Example:

```
63 * x = 1
```

How to find x? In this case it's approximately `0.0158730159`

---

I apologize if the question was asked (most likely so!), I probably lack knowledge of terminology and keywords to find it by search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just divide both sides of the equation by $63$:
\begin{align*}
63x &=1 \\
\frac{1}{63}\times 63x &= \frac{1}{63} \times 1\\
x &= \frac{1}{63}.
\end{align*}

In general, if you want to solve $ax = b$, you multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{a}$:
\begin{align*}
ax &=b \\
\frac{1}{a}\times ax &= \frac{1}{a} \times b\\
x &= \frac{b}{a}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I was overthinking, and it was way simpler than I thought. Thank you!